# How to fetch individual tweets by id?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter

What's the best way to fetch a set of tweets by ID in the Scala + Spark ecosystem? Given a list of IDs, I'd like to easily produce an RDD containing the actual tweets.

There's plenty of resources online about Spark and the Twitter streaming API, but I haven't found anything similar for fetching particular tweets.

Comment: You would like to fetch particular tweets from streaming API itself or do you want to select particular tweets from the list of tweets which you already streamed?

Comment: can you share ur sample dataseta and expected output format ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you want.

> GET statuses/lookup
>   Returns fully-hydrated Tweet objects for up to 100
>   Tweets per request, as specified by comma-separated values passed to
>   the id parameter.

See [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup)

Wrapped in Twitter4J [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TweetsResources.html#lookup-long...-)

> Returns fully-hydrated tweet objects for up to 100 tweets per request,
>   as specified by comma-separated values passed to the id parameter.
>   This method is especially useful to get the details (hydrate) a
>   collection of Tweet IDs.  This method calls
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json